# Does the glibc getaddrinfo vulnerability affect mobile applications?

Tags: dns, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability, glibc

Recently Google discovered the ["glibc getaddrinfo" vulnerability (CVE-2015-7547)](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html)

Is this a server side only issue, or can apps be affected by it as well? I'm developing both an iPhone and Android app, and don't know exactly what to look for, or what to update.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Android nor iPhone use glibc, so these are not affected.
Android uses as libc [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) and iOS is also using their own libc implementation.

Comment: Not even by using a library like AFNetworking or something like that?

Comment: @Jan: no, not even then.

Comment: Google wrote their own library that wraps the libc type stuff, Bionic.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is affected, for example. The update is scheduled for today.